# Why every time I accept an assassin contract, a bird leaves the cage?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag, every time I accept an assassin contract, a bird (pigeon I think) leaves the cage.

Is there something to it, or is it just random?

Comment: Imprisoning pigeons is cruel. Better to not give them a reason to conquer the earth.

Comment: @davidyell the trick is to eat them before they eat you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a carrier pigeon. It's carrying the details of the contract back.  [The details can be found here on the Assassin's Creed Wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassination_contracts).